# creating combinations from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, combinations

Im trying to figure out how to take a list of lists of integers and create a new list that contains combinations from the list of lists. I want the combination to start with a value from the first list and then respectively take 1 from each of the subsequent lists, only if the value is greater than the previous list.

```
l=[[1,2,3],[4,8],[5,10]]



# the answer would look like this 
correct=[[1,4,5],[1,4,10],[1,8,10],[2,4,5],[2,4,10],[2,8,10],[3,4,5],[3,4,10],[3,8,10]]
```

Comment: How much of it did you try?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import product
... 
... 
... def combos(lst):
...     result = []
...     for p in product(*lst):
...         if all(a < b for a, b in zip(p, p[1:])):
...             result.append(list(p))
...     return result
... 
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 8], [5, 10]]
>>> correct = [[1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 10], [1, 8, 10], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 10],
...            [2, 8, 10], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 10], [3, 8, 10]]
>>> combos(lst) == correct
True
```

Comment: This is not valid. `(2, 8, 5)` According to question, elements must be in sorted  order in accordance to given list.

Comment: You think 5 is greater than 8?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Cool. :)

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension is probably a great way to go. It works nicely because of your constraints. You probably want something like:

```
[[i,j,k] for i in l[0] for j in l[1] if j>i for k in l[2] if k>j]
>>> [[1, 4, 5],
    [1, 4, 10],
    [1, 8, 10],
    [2, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 10],
    [2, 8, 10],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [3, 4, 10],
    [3, 8, 10]]
```

This makes a list of lists of the form [i,j,k] for all the i's in l[0] for all the j's in l[1] if j>i and for all the k's in l[2] if k>j (since we already know that j>i at this point)

---

However, the code above only works for an input list of list of length 3. Took me a little bit, but this recursive approach should work for a input list of any length

```
def list_of_lists(in_list):
    full_list=[]

    def recurse(so_far, l):
        if l==len(in_list):
            return so_far 
        next_list = in_list[l]
        for i in next_list:
            if i>so_far[-1]:
                new_list = recurse(so_far.copy()+[i], l+1)
                if new_list:
                    full_list.append(new_list)

    for i in in_list[0]:
        recurse([i],1)
    return full_list
```

Comment: Recursion isn't always a great option in Python. [`itertools.product`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aa0735f597b072c0eb00404c4d7df359ddc26755/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2031) is implemented in C and using `all` can handle however many arguments needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[[1,2,3],
    [4,8],
    [5,10]]

ansList = []

for i in range(len(l[0])):
    for j in range(len(l[1])):
        for k in range(len(l[2])):
            if l[0][i]<l[1][j] and l[1][j]<l[2][k]:
                ansList.append([l[0][i],l[1][j],l[2][k]])

print(ansList)
```